# Lightning UI New Opportunity Dashboard

Tags: lightning-experience, opportunity, dashboard

We are testing the new Lightning UI in our Sandbox and are trying to show the new benefits during a presentation tomorrow to our Sales team.  However, there is one part on the initial home screen we cannot get to work:

[image: Error in Lightning UI]

I have tried many things to get this working :

- I have switched on Forecasting which was previously not used
- I have added myself to the forecast hierarchy/territory and have some opportunities allocated to me
- I have created opportunities inside the territory and they appear in the forecast/opportunity screen
- I even tried a little dance with a silly hat on my head whilst hitting F5 several times

Suffice to say I have tried as much as I can think of to try and get it working.  Any other suggestions are gratefully received

Answer (score 2):

as you can imagine I posted this question to a few different forums.

I found our specific error was related to the fact that we had hidden the "Probability" on the field level security.

Here is the link which helped me - there is a chart about half way down which helps describes the steps to get the chart working:

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_more